# Assign id where object is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here is my problem. I am struggling with this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
37:               <ul class="dropdown">
38:                 <li><%= link_to 'Add Info', new_developer_developer_info_path(current_user.id) %></li>
39:                 <li><%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_developer_registration_path %></li>
40:                 <li><%= link_to 'Edit Info', edit_developer_developer_info_path(current_user.id, current_user.developer_info.id) %></li>
41:               </ul>
42:             </li>
43:             <li><%= link_to 'Dashboard', developer_path(current_user) %></li>
```

When a developer(user) is signing up it redirects him to the profile page where there is a navbar (devise). The navbar has a dropdown menu with an edit link. If my developer has already registered then I get no errors because I have an id present for `current_user.developer_info.id`, but if he hasn't registered then I get an error `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`.

The solution I found here so far is to create an instance of class `@developer_info = DeveloperInfo.new` in appropriate controller and pass it `@developer_info.id` to `application.html.erb`. But which controller do I have to use? Am I on right direction to fix my problem? I don't have access to `devise` controller where my developer is signing up. Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: I recommend showing that link if only `current_user` has `developer_info`

Comment: in the page, you are are showing options to add a developer info, edit the user profile etc, so it should clearly only be shown if user is signed_in. Include `before_action :authenticate_user` in your controller

Comment: pass the method name with `only: [:my_dashboard_action]` if you selectively want to enable it for few actions alone

Comment: Did you get this fixed yet?

Comment: @RockwellRice Yes I did. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @RockwellRice done:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest would be to just put a check for a current user's developer_info and hide/show the link.  If the user is not registered there is nothing to edit so no need to show anything.

```
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><%= link_to 'Add Info', new_developer_developer_info_path(current_user.id) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_developer_registration_path %></li>

  <% if current_user.developer_info %>
   <li><%= link_to 'Edit Info', edit_developer_developer_info_path(current_user.id, current_user.developer_info.id) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```